# Keep track of object types

Tags: c++, templates

What I'm trying to achieve is to keep track of what types of objects we're created that inherit from a base class. If a class inherits from the base class but is not instantiated in an object I'm not that interested in tracking that (this condition can be included or not depending if the implementation is easier or not)

Dummy example:

```
template <typename T>
class Person
{
public:
    Person() {
        T* x;
        container.push_back(x);
    }
    virtual ~Person() {}
private:
    static heterogeneous_container container;
};

class Employee : public Person <Employee>
{
};

class Employee2 : public Employee
{
};
```

Also, I would like this to work for chained inheritance. Is it possible that when I instantiate an Employee2, the base class Person will add an Employee2 type pointer in the container?

As for the heterogeneous container, I think this can be used [link](https://gieseanw.wordpress.com/2017/05/03/a-true-heterogeneous-container-in-c/)

Comment: Note that the base class is not `Person`, it is `Person<Employee>`.  That may or may not be what you want.  Did you intend `container` to be a static member?  At the moment, each object will have its own `container` with exactly one pointer in it.

Comment: @MartinBonner you're right, the container should be static. I edited the question. As for the base class, I want to provide a simple way to pass the derived class type to the base class so that the base class handles the types tracking

Comment: can you clarify if the base should store pointers to the objects or only the type information? From the text I understand it is the second, but in the code it looks like the first. Currently you have answers for both variants.

Comment: I need the types, I thought that storing pointers is a way to store the types without creating or instantiating a new object of that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More or less, I have somewhere working like that :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

struct ClassEntry {
    size_t id = 0;
    const char* label;
};

class BaseClass {
public:
protected:

    static void RegisterType(size_t id, const char * label) {
        ClassEntry entry;
        entry.id = id;
        entry.label = label;
        mRegisteredTypes.emplace_back(entry);

        std::cout << "Registered type " << id << " label " << label << std::endl;
    }

    static size_t createId() {
        static size_t id = 0;
        return id++;
    }

    static std::vector<ClassEntry> mRegisteredTypes;
};

std::vector<ClassEntry> BaseClass::mRegisteredTypes;


class OneTimeCall {
public:
    OneTimeCall(std::function<void(void)>&& func)  {
        func();
    }
    virtual ~OneTimeCall() {

    }
};


template<typename T>
class MyClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    MyClass() {
        static OneTimeCall one_time {
            [this]{
                BaseClass::RegisterType(GetId(), T::GetType());
            }
        };


    }
private:

protected:

    static size_t GetId() {
        static size_t id = BaseClass::createId();
        return id;
    }
};


class A : public MyClass<A> {
public:
    A() {

    }

   static const char *GetType() {
        return "ClassA";
   }
};

class B : public MyClass<B> {
public:
    B() {

    }

    static const char *GetType() {
        return "ClassB";
    }
};


int main() {

    A a;
    B b;
    A a2;
    B b2;


    return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
Registered type 0 label ClassA
Registered type 1 label ClassB
```

The main idea is to use CRTP and static initialization in construction for register each type only one time. It works without problems in linux, on windows compiler the static BaseClass ID is new on each DLL, so you need to tune a bit for use in a external library.

With this approach you dont need any external library and is possible to compile without rtti.

For inheritance you can create a new class:

```
template<typename Current, typename Base>
class Mix : public MyClass<Current>, public Base {};
```

So if you pass "type C" as current type (CRTP) and type A as base class can work.

```
class C : public Mix<C, A> {
public:
    C() {

    }

    static const char *GetType() {
        return "ClassC";
    }
};
```

With this approach if you have previously registered "A" it will not be registered again, and if you dont have "A" it will be registered after "C".

Comment: What happens if I define class B like this: 

class B : public A {};

Comment: The thing is that I need make it work for chain inheritance also. I came across the CRTP pattern but it seems it brakes when using chained inheritance

Comment: Indeed this works, I find it a bit difficult that each time you have to remember to inherit from the Mix class and not directly from from your base class. It will allow a new developer to do stuff like       class C : public Mix<B,A>

Comment: Is easy to decouple here the autoregister mechanism from the inheritance mechanism, and at the end you can inherit directly from A and if you need autoregister can inherit also from a crtp autoregister like: class C : public A, public Autoregister<C> or something like that.

Comment: A define can also help a bit: #define Class(cl, base) class cl : public Mix<cl, base>

Answer (score 4):

I think what you want is more like:

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person() {
        objects.push_back(this);
    }
    virtual ~Person() {
        objects.erase(this);
    }
private:
    static std::set<const Person*> objects;
};

class Employee : public Person
{
};

class Employee2 : public Employee
{
};
```

With this approach, you can enquire the dynamic type of the most-derived object that each of the pointers in the container points to.

Note that the `objects` set has to contain the pointers, *not* the type_info for each object.  The problem is that inside the constructor for the `Person` sub-object of an `Employee2` object, the most-derived type of `*this` will be `Person`, not `Employee2` (it won't become `Employee2` until execution enters the `Employee2` constructor).

Comment: I think that here you don't need templates anymore ? And objects variable is refering to container variable ? I there a way to know that the stored this pointer is of type Employee or Employee2? For example I would like to add a print() function to Person class that will go over the container and print all the types it stored.

Comment: @user1934513 you can use `typeid`, which will return a `std::type_info` corresponding to the *runtime* type of the object. Note also that the string values returned by the `name` member are implementation defined. Often they have been "mangled"

Comment: I would add that actual type of objects can now be printed using RTTI with std::type_info

Comment: @Caleth oh didnt know that `typeid` considers the runtime type of the object... time to delete my non-answer ;)

Comment: My thanks to whoever tried to remove the template and simplify the erase - unfortunately it clashed with my edit so it got auto-rejected.  I have incorporated your change.

Comment: I think that std::set has no efect because whenever you create two Employee objects for example, "this" pointer will have a different value for each created obejct so you'll end up with two elements in the set. Besides this, I think this should work.

Comment: @user1934513 Yes, this will create two pointers.  The `set` is useful because it makes easy to remove the pointer when the object is deleted.

Comment: @MartinBonner is it possible to have two coutners per class type: created and alive ? For example I would like to know how many objects of type Employee2 were ever created and how many are still alive. Not removing elements from the set I would say it's not an option. This is a bit challenging because as you said typeid(*this) returns the base class when called from the constructor or destructor.

Answer (score 0):

One way to track objects is to store them an intrusive list and embed a link node into the objects. This provides `noexcept` guarantee for tracker operations and doesn't require an extra memory allocation when inserting the elements into the tracker container, for the price of an embedded list node (two pointers) in each tracked object:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/intrusive/list.hpp>

namespace bi = boost::intrusive;

template<class T>
class Tracker : public bi::list_base_hook<bi::link_mode<bi::auto_unlink>>
{
protected:
    static bi::list<Tracker, bi::constant_time_size<false>> objects_;

    Tracker() noexcept { objects_.push_back(*this); }
    Tracker(Tracker const&) noexcept { objects_.push_back(*this); }

public:
    static auto count() noexcept { return objects_.size(); }
};

template<class T>
bi::list<Tracker<T>, bi::constant_time_size<false>> Tracker<T>::objects_;

struct Employee : Tracker<Employee> {};
struct Employee2 : Employee {};

int main() {
    std::cout << Tracker<Employee>::count() << '\n';
    {
        Employee e0;
        Employee2 e1;
        std::cout << Tracker<Employee>::count() << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << Tracker<Employee>::count() << '\n';
}
```

Outputs:

```
0
2
0
```

---

`Tracker` without Boost library:

```
struct AutoListNode {
    AutoListNode *next_ = this, *prev_ = this;

    AutoListNode() noexcept = default;
    AutoListNode(AutoListNode const&) = delete;
    AutoListNode& operator=(AutoListNode const&) = delete;
    ~AutoListNode() noexcept { this->erase(); }

    void push_back(AutoListNode* node) noexcept {
        auto prev = prev_;
        node->prev_ = prev;
        node->next_ = this;
        prev->next_ = node;
        prev_ = node;
    }

    void erase() noexcept {
        auto next = next_;
        auto prev = prev_;
        prev->next_ = next;
        next->prev_ = prev;
    }

    size_t size() const noexcept {
        size_t count = 0;
        for(auto node = next_; node != this; node = node->next_)
            ++count;
        return count;
    }
};

template<class T>
class Tracker : private AutoListNode
{
protected:
    static AutoListNode objects_;

    Tracker() noexcept { objects_.push_back(this); }
    Tracker(Tracker const&) noexcept { objects_.push_back(this); }

public:
    static auto count() noexcept { return objects_.size(); }
};

template<class T>
AutoListNode Tracker<T>::objects_;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, at the moment I will try to avoid boost

Comment: @user1934513 Added a version without Boost library for you.